# Texture issue in BGE (Transition from Multitexture to GLSL)

Tags: texturing, game-engine

I am working on a game inspired of Jet Set Radio style wise, and for that reason i edited my models directly with a set of color to respect my game's color palette. However, when i switched to GLSL to have a preview of what the game's models will look like, no textures were showing up, they were just blank. I tried making materials with "Face texture" on, but that didn't work. I've also tried to bake my textures using Cycles Render but again, it didn't work either.

What it's supposed to look like :
[image]

And what i get in GLSL :
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try posting the blend file, it might help someone figure out what is going on. Did you set up your material nodes of BGE?

Comment: Well yes, i have set up material nodes and everything. I just can't bake or apply textures in GLSL, and i'm really pissed off now because i spent an entire afternoon trying to figure out how to fix this thing. also i can't really share my project file because my internet is really slow atm, i'll try uploading it tomorrow.

Comment: Okay go for the upload, and I'll see what i can do on Sunday.